# column pk dual varchars or int?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Imagine a table that has a `JobID` and a `SubJobID`.

The combination of `JobID + SubJobID` make the row unique.

For instance:

```
JobID = CAX100
SubJobID = CA00

JobID = CAX200RW
SubJobID = CA00

JobID = CAX200YYXZ
SubJobID = CA01

etc...
```

These are valid rows, but if I try to again insert `JobID=CAX100` and `SubJobID=CA00` then this is not allowed and should error.

So currently should I keep `JobID` and `SubJobID` the combination of both as a primary key?  Or should I introduce an int as a primary key (maybe an autoincrement int)? I know ints are better and smaller for primary keys, but then how do I ensure the uniqueness of `JobID + SubJobID` if I introduce a number as a primary key?

Currently I have `JobID` and `SubJobID` as composite primary keys I understand that, that is what I currently have, but what is recommended having both columns as pk (varchar) or introduce a new column (int type with auto number) and create a unique constraint on `JobID + SubJobID`?

Comment: Define both columns as the primary key.

Comment: Add a unique constraint if you don't want a compound PK

Comment: Why use varchar? Anyway, I'm of the view that _every_ table should have a distinct unique primary Id column.

Comment: Multiply `JobID` by 100 and allow addition.

Comment: juergen d - I understand that, that is what I currently have, but what is recommended having both columns as pk (varchar, because they are varchar) or introduce a new column (int type with auto number) and create a unique constraint on the jobid and subjobid?

Comment: You still haven't answered the question about why obviously numeric columns are varchar. If it's so that you can maintain a leading 0 on a SubJobID, stop doing that, and pad with 0s at presentation time.

Comment: @GrantThomas - why varchar?  Because jobid and subjobid are expressed as a string.  That is why I am asking....is it best to keep the composite pk (of this varchar type) or create an additional int pk (autonumber) with a unique constraint on jobid and subjobid.  Im also on the  view that every table should have a distinct unique primary key, see my question as I have mentioned the combination of both jobid and subjobid is unique.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Sorry my question used a bad example, a job is not really a number, it is something to the effect of CXY100 with subjobid AB100.  My appologies

Comment: @AaronBertrand -  I have updated my question to reflect real jobid rather then 100.

Comment: Are you going to reference this combination from other tables? If not, then I don't know what possible purpose an additional primary key column would serve. You're certainly not going to save any space by adding another column, creating a primary key there, and having to have a unique constraint on the two columns anyway.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yes I will have to reference the combination in other tables...that is where I was stuck..should I reference both columns or introduce the int pk column?

Comment: There is no perfect answer to your question - it really depends. Are the references from other tables 1:1, 100:1, 10000000000:1?

Comment: @AaronBertrand THank you for taking the time to ask great questions.  The references are generally 1 to many so let me give you an example.  I have another table that stores attachments (links) for the project and subproject.  So the combination of JobID and SubJobID would point back to many rows in the attachments table (One JobID SubJobID has many attachments) this is just one example.

Comment: Does an attachment only ever belong to a SubJobID? Then again I think it makes more sense to split these tables out. You have a Jobs table, then a SubJobs table that has a foreign key to the Jobs table, and then Attachments has a foreign key to the SubJobs table (from which you can easily derive the JobID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a surrogate autoincrement integer column, you still need a unique index on the JobID, SubJobID columns. This is the natural primary key.

It may not add much value except using more disk and memory to store the extra column.

Saying that, if the composite (JobID, SubJobID) index is used in child tables as a foreign key, it can make more sense to use one. 10000 rows here could have 10 million child rows: then the varchar overhead matters.

However, there is no truth in anything you read that says

> Thou shalt always have an identity/autoincrement primary key

It is an implementation decision for performance depending on the design.

Comment: +1 These are the types of answers I like.  So you are saying to stick with my current composite primary key of the two columns (Even though they are varchar) ?

Comment: Yes, subject to my edit. A surrogate key is merely for efficiency in some circumstances

Comment: I think you are pretty much aware of the issues, from the question.  How about this as an 'out there' idea?  Normalise the data into 2 tables, `jobs` & `subjobs` ...

Comment: Yes that is the only issue I can think of is I need to reference the combination of JobID and SubJobID in other tables...so would this be a good candidate to introduce the int column pk ?

Comment: @HughJones: Probably correct, but we don't have enough information to know if this is what should be done

Comment: @gbn - totally agree.  The OP is the only one who can really answer this question

Comment: @oJM86o: then this is where a surrogate key comes in useful, to avoid repeating an inefficient key in child table. Inefficient is relative of course: I've used a 14 column primary key on a billion row table and it was 70% smaller than having a surrogate key and unique index. There were no child tables in this case of course.

Comment: Not just performance - a surrogate key can make for much cleaner and more readable client-code & Sql.  Your point is well made, though - there is no hard and fast rule.

Comment: @HughJones - I think you put it the best way, there is no hard and fast rule to this..it depends on the business case and only I can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would define an integer Primary Key and a unique index on the 2 varchar fields.  This is assuming that your database application is non-trivial and performance is an issue.

If you only have a few dozen records in this table, on the other hand, it is possible to over-engineer things.

Comment: I always feel this is MS Access style design..what is the purpose of an integer primary key if both columns make the row a unique row?

Comment: The only advantage would be if this table is small and the other tables that reference it are very large - you pay for more storage in this table to reduce the storage required by the referencing rows in other tables.

Comment: Integer keys perform considerably better than strings.

Comment: Hugh be careful about over-generalizing. If the table were not being referenced by foreign key columns, I don't think a system will perform better if it has an extra column to store and an extra index to maintain, when that column serves no other purpose than to identify the row uniquely (which you can always do). This isn't true in the OP's case, but your statement sounds very sweeping, and matches the defense a lot of people use when they throw an IDENTITY column on every. single. table.

Comment: @Aaron - yes fair point, in fact the surrogate key would make inserts a little bit slower ...

Comment: @HughJones: see my comment on my answer about my billion row table. No foreign keys to it, no surrogate key, 70% smaller on disk and in RAM.